# Get effect of regex /a prior to Perl 5.14

Tags: regex, perl, backwards-compatibility

I'm working on some code with unusually high backward compatibility requirements: it must work correctly by Perl >= 5.6.0 (yes, you read that right, 5.6.0) and cannot safely assume the existence of most of the core modules.

In one place in this code I need to convert unprintable characters to \xNN escapes for display in an error message.  With the features of more modern Perl,

```
    $text =~ s/[^\x20-\x7e]/"\\x".sprintf("%02x", ord($&))/aeg;
```

does the job.  However, prior to Perl 5.14 the `/a` modifier causes a compile-time error.

How do I get the effect of `/a` in Perl 5.6 through 5.12?  A single construct that works over the entire range of versions from 5.6 through present would be preferable, if possible; failing that, something that works in all cases where `/a` is *not* available would be fine.  Solutions that do not use modules are strongly preferred.  EBCDIC support is not necessary.

Comment: Wild guess, but have you tried `/aa`?

Comment: Has the modifier 'a' even an effect here? When the code is meant to work with Perl 5.6 then $text must be without wide characters. Then I see no reason why the modifier a should have an effect on the character class `[^\x20-\x7e]`. So simply remove it.

Comment: @BarneySchmale The code needs to work with _both_ Perl 5.6-12 and 5.14-present.  And $text comes from untrusted input so there is no reason to think it _cannot_ contain wide characters.

Comment: @RawleyFowler Neither `/a` nor `/aa` is understood by old perls. You get a syntax error.

Answer (score 7):

`/a` affects what `\d`, `\s` and `\w` match. It similarly affects POSIX character classes (`[[:name:]]`).

To safely remove the `/a`, make the following substitutions:

| Affected | Replacement | Replacement (5.10+) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `\d` and `[\d]` | `[0-9]` | `\p{PosixDigit}` |
| `\s` and `[\s]` | `[ \f\n\r\t\cK]` or `[\x09-\x0D\x20]` | `\p{PosixSpace}` |
| `\w` and `[\w]` | `[A-Za-z0-9_]` | `\p{PosixWord}` |
| `[[:alpha:]]` | `[A-Za-z]` | `\p{PosixAlpha}` |
| `[[:alnum:]]` | `[A-Za-z0-9_]` | `\p{PosixAlnum}` |
| `[[:blank:]]` | `[ \t]` or `[\x09\x20]` | `\p{PosixBlank}` |
| `[[:cntrl:]]` | `[\x00-\x1F\x7F]` | `\p{PosixCntrl}` |
| `[[:digit:]]` | `[0-9]` | `\p{PosixDigit}` |
| `[[:graph:]]` | `[\x21-\x7E]` | `\p{PosixGraph}` |
| `[[:lower:]]` | `[a-z]` | `\p{PosixLower}` |
| `[[:print:]]` | `[\x20-\x7E]` | `\p{PosixPrint}` |
| `[[:punct:]]` | `[\x21-\x2F\x3A-\x40\x5B-\x60\x7B-\x7E]` | `\p{PosixPunct}` |
| `[[:space:]]` | `[ \f\n\r\t]` or `[\x09-\x0D\x20]` | `\p{PosixSpace}` |
| `[[:upper:]]` | `[A-Z]` | `\p{PosixUpper}` |
| `[[:word:]]` | `[A-Za-z0-9_]` | `\p{PosixWord}` |
| `[[:xdigit:]]` | `[0-9a-fA-F]` | `\p{PosixXDigit}` |

(There's one other POSIX character class, `[[:ascii:]]`. However, it's not affected by `/a`.)

---

Since the pattern in the question uses none of those classes, `/a` has no effect on it, and the `/a` can simply be removed.

Comment: Hmm, this may mean /a wasn't even what I wanted in the first place...

Comment: @zwol, Accept answer?